# Extension manifest must request permission to access this host

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, google-chrome-extension

I am trying to append a div to page of current active tab. However I am getting this error:

```
Error during tabs.executeScript: Cannot access contents of url .... 
Extension manifest must request permission to access this host.
```

My Code: (show_loader.js)

```
var dv = document.createElement('div');
dv.id = 'myid';
dv.innerHTML = 'test';
document.body.appendChild(dv);
```

However when I put this code:

```
document.body.style.backgroundColor = 'green';
```

**It works as expected** and background color of current tab is changed with no other change except for the code in show_loader.js file which is run from popup.js like this:

```
chrome.tabs.executeScript(null, {file: "show_loader.js"});
```

My Manifest file also does have:

```
"permissions":
[
  "tabs",
  "notifications",
  "http://*/",
  "https://*/"
],
```

So I wonder why it gives above error when I try to do anything else other than setting background color. Even simple `alert` or `console.log` alone on that page gives same above mentioned error.

How to fix that ?

### Update: Complete Relevant Code

Manifest:

```
{
   ... name and description ...
   "icons":
   {
      "16" : "img/icon.png",
      "48" : "img/48.png",
      "128" : "img/128.png"
   },
   
   "permissions":
   [
      "tabs",
      "notifications",
      "http://*/*",
      "https://*/*"
   ],
   
   "browser_action":
   {
      "default_icon": "img/icon.png", 
      "default_title": "Page title",      
      "default_popup": "popup.html"       
   }
}
```

popup.js

```
// send data to server for saving
$('#btn').click(function(){

     chrome.tabs.executeScript(null, {file: "show_loader.js"});

      $loader.show();

      var data = $(this).closest('form').serialize();

      $.ajax({.....});

});

window.onload = function(){
    var $loader = $('#loader');
    $loader.show();
    
    chrome.tabs.getSelected(null, function(tab) {
        //console.log(tab);
        $('#url').val(tab.url); 
        $('#title').val(tab.title);
        $loader.hide();
    });
};
```

popup.html

```
<html>
<head>
   <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/style.css" type="text/css" />
</head>
<body>
    
   <form action="" method="post" name="frm" id="frm">
   <table border="0" cellpadding="3" cellspecing="0" width="370">
      ......
   </table>
   </form>

<script src='js/jquery.js'></script>
<script src='popup.js?v=014423432423'></script> 

</body>
</html>
```

show_loader.js

```
console.log($); // doesn't work

// document.body.style.backgroundColor = 'green'; // WORKS
```

Comment: Try changing your permissions to `"http://*/*"` and `"https://*/*"` (note the trailing asterisk)

Comment: @rgthree: Unfortunately still the same error :( I think issue might be some other since background color change code works with same manifest permissions.

Comment: @dev02: At what point of time this code `chrome.tabs.executeScript` is being called in `popup.js` ?

Comment: @Sudarshan: It is called on a button click which exists in popup.html file. At same place it works if i change background not for anything else

Comment: @dev02: I just tried a sample it works fine, is the page you are executing in loading state?, share your complete relevant code, it seems the problem appears to be another issue unrelated to this

Comment: @Sudarshan: Nope it isn't in loading state. Let me update the question with code.

Comment: @Sudarshan: Updated the question with relevant code.

Comment: @dev02: `chrome.tabs.getSelected` is deprecated use chrome.tabs.query() instead and let me know if you still face problem?

Comment: @dev02: and why `<script src='popup.js?v=014423432423'></script> ` in your popup.html ?

Comment: @Sudarshan: `<script src='popup.js?v=014423432423'></script>` works. How should it be then ? Can you also share your code on pastebin or elsewhere you say it works for you ?

Comment: @Sudarshan: Is this correct way to use query for current tab? `chrome.tabs.query({}, function (tabs) { $('#url').val(tabs.currentWindow.url); });`

Comment: @dev02:Check my answer for sample usage and my working version of code

Answer (score 45, accepted):

Code which worked

#### manifest.json

```
{
    "name": "Manifest Permissions",
    "description": "http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14361061/extension-manifest-must-request-permission-to-access-this-host",
    "version": "1",
    "manifest_version": 2,
    "browser_action": {
        "default_popup": "popup.html"
    },
    "permissions": [
        "tabs",
        "notifications",
        "http://*/",
        "https://*/"
    ]
}
```

#### popup.html

```
<html>

    <head>
        <script src="back.js"></script>
    </head>

    <body>
        <button id="tmp-clipboard">Click Me</button>
    </body>

</html>
```

#### back.js

```
document.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", function () {
    document.getElementById('tmp-clipboard').onclick = function () {
        chrome.tabs.executeScript(null, {
            file: "script.js"
        });
    }
});
```

#### script.js

```
var dv = document.createElement('div');
dv.id = 'myid';
dv.innerHTML = 'test';
document.body.appendChild(dv);
```

Try Eliminating deprecated `chrome.tabs.getSelected` from your code and use [chrome.tabs.query](http://developer.chrome.com/extensions/tabs.html#method-query) instead.

### Sample Usage

```
chrome.tabs.query({
    "currentWindow": true,
    "status": true,
    "active": true //Add any parameters you want
}, function (tabs) {//It returns an array
    for (tab in tabs) {
        //Do your stuff here
    }
});
```

## Edit 1

If you intention is to capture active browsing tab in current window where he clicked `browser action` use this code

```
chrome.tabs.query({
    "currentWindow": true,//Filters tabs in current window
    "status": "complete", //The Page is completely loaded
    "active": true // The tab or web page is browsed at this state,
    "windowType": "normal" // Filters normal web pages, eliminates g-talk notifications etc
}, function (tabs) {//It returns an array
    for (tab in tabs) {
        $('#url').val(tabs[tab].url); 
        $('#title').val(tabs[tab].title);
        $loader.hide(); 
    }
});
```

Comment: Thanks for taking time to help and answer. I will mark this as accepted and try out but one question. How would you replace `chrome.tabs.getSelected(null, function(tab) {$('#url').val(tab.url); });` with `tabs.query` version ?

Comment: @dev02: Check EDIT 1 of my answer

Comment: Thanks I asked but I thought iterating over `tabs` will affect all tabs. Thanks for your help again :)

Comment: Looks like the page that chrome says there is not network can not run code on it no matter what permission you said in manifest.js

Answer (score 50):

The manifest v3 uses a different [permission schema](https://developer.chrome.com/docs/extensions/mv3/declare_permissions/). This is what worked for me:

```json
    "host_permissions": [
        "https://music.youtube.com/*"
    ],
```

Comment: `"host_permissions": ["https://*/*"]` for all hosts in case anyone else needs it.

Comment: I use "host_permissions": [*://*/"] so that I'm not restricted to https.

Answer (score 3):

The following code worked for me:

```
"manifest_version": 3,
"host_permissions": ["<all_urls>"],
```

Comment: @Cristik: previous answer does not mention `all_urls` at all!

Comment: Fair point, @pathikrit