# Chrome Extension displays context menu with left click without popup

Tags: google-chrome, google-chrome-extension

Just starting to learn how to write a Chrome Extension. My goal is to write to a console from a background js when the toolbar icon is clicked.

My understanding from tutorials that I have read is that, when popup is not specified, the icon would act like a button, and that when it is left-clicked, onClicked callback is called. What actually happens instead is that left-click displays a default context menu; callback is never called - probably for this reason.

I am sure I am missing something very basic; it would be very helpful if someone can point it out. For the record, I am using Chrome version 80.0.3987.163 on Mac.

Thank you all in advance.

Manifest:

```
{
    "name": "Test",
    "version": "1.0",
    "description": "",

    "manifest_version": 2,

    "permissions": ["declarativeContent"],

    "page_action": {
        "default_icon": {
          "16": "images/get_started16.png",
          "32": "images/get_started32.png",
          "48": "images/get_started48.png",
          "128": "images/get_started128.png"
        }
    },

    "icons": {
        "16": "images/get_started16.png",
        "32": "images/get_started32.png",
        "48": "images/get_started48.png",
        "128": "images/get_started128.png"
    },

    "content_scripts": [
        {
          "matches": ["*://*.reddit.com/r/*"],
          "js": ["content.js"]
        }
      ],

    "background": {
        "scripts": ["background.js"],
        "persistent": false
    }
}
```

content.js:

```
console.log("Content script running...");
```

background.js:

```
console.log("Background script running...");

const iconRules = [{
    conditions: [
        new chrome.declarativeContent.PageStateMatcher({
            pageUrl: {hostEquals: 'reddit.com'},
        })
    ],
    actions: [new chrome.declarativeContent.ShowPageAction()]
}];

chrome.declarativeContent.onPageChanged.removeRules(undefined, function() {
    chrome.declarativeContent.onPageChanged.addRules(iconRules);
});

chrome.pageAction.onClicked.addListener(function(){
    chrome.tabs.query({active: true, currentWindow: true}, function(tabs) {
        console.log("Clicked!")
    })
});
```

Upon visiting reddit:

[Shows highlighted icon.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vzF9p.jpg)

When the icon is left-clicked:

[A default context menu displays.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/kacSn.jpg)

Comment: 1. Check out some simple official examples [here](https://chromium.googlesource.com/chromium/src/+/master/chrome/common/extensions/docs/examples/api/pageAction/). 2. In the last bit of code of `onClicked` listener inside the callback function you can set it as `function(tab)` since that is the argument it can return which you can then use below along with this function: `chrome.tabs.executeScript(tab.id, {code: 'console.log("Clicked!")'});`, instead of finding the whole tab again via `tabs.query`.

Comment: BTW host name is `www.reddit.com`, not `reddit.com`, Chrome just hides the www part. Double-click the URL to see it in full or [disable shortening](https://superuser.com/questions/1333575/chrome-address-bar-no-longer-shows-protocol-or-www-subdomain) completely. You see the menu because the icon is not enabled, most probably due to the wrong host name.

Comment: Thank you for the comments and the tip on the callback. I just came to the same conclusion and provided the answer. I do not know why the Chrome does not choose to grey out the icon, however.

Comment: Changing the callback as suggested above creates a permission-related runtime error in the background script. My original approach doesn't. I will need to investigate the difference; but I just wanted to note this observation here.

Comment: I believe this is related: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14361061/extension-manifest-must-request-permission-to-access-this-host.

Answer (score 0):

After experimenting more, I finally figured out why this was not working: the pageURL was not matching.

The actual host is www.reddit.com. Changing the hostEquals to hostSuffix stopped Chrome from displaying the context menu; onClicked callback was called.

I have no idea why Chrome even activates the icon when the condition doesn't match.

Comment: Modern Chrome doesn't gray out the icon when your manifest has a permission for the host. Declaring a content script adds that permission. Actually there's no point in using page action anymore.